# Multiplication group modulo n is well defined,associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

For positive integers N>1, the positive integers less than N and coprime to N form a multiplicative group modulo N.

How can I prove that the multiplication table for this group is well defined?

How can I prove that this group satisfies the associative group axiom? It's easy to prove the closure axiom and identity/inverse axiom, but I have no idea how to prove associativity.

Comment: **Hint**: is the multiplication inherited from some structure on which associativity is known?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\overline a$ denote the class of the integer $a\in \mathbb Z$ modulo $N$.
We are working in $$G=\{\overline a\in \mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z\,:\,\textrm{gcd}\,(a,n)=1\}.$$
You said that you proved the "closure" axiom so I assume you know that the product in $G$ is just $\overline a\cdot\overline b:=\overline{ab}$, where $ab$ denotes the product in $\mathbb Z$. Hence
$$(\overline{a}\cdot\overline b)\cdot \overline c=\overline{ab}\cdot \overline c=\overline{(ab)c}\overset{\ast}{=}\overline{a(bc)}=\overline{a}\cdot\overline{bc}=\overline a\cdot(\overline b\cdot \overline c).$$
We used associativity in $\mathbb Z$ in $\ast$.

*Added*. Let us show $\overline a\cdot \overline b=\overline{ab}$ is well-defined. Let us change the representatives:
$$\overline a=\overline{a'},\,\,\,\,\,\overline b=\overline{b'}.$$
This means $$a-a'=hN,\,\,\,\,\,b-b'=kN\,\,\,\,\,\textrm{some }h,k\in\mathbb Z.$$
We have to show that changing representatives does not change the result, i.e. our claim is: $\overline{a'}\cdot \overline{b'}=\overline{ab}$. So:
$$\overline{a'}\cdot \overline{b'}=\overline{a'b'}=\overline{(a+hN)(b+kN)}=\overline{ab+N(ak+bh+hkN)}=\overline{ab}.$$

Comment: Thanks. This is the prove for associativity. Can you prove the multiplication table is well defined?

Answer (score 2):

To check that an operation is well-defined, the usual issue is that you're defining the operation on *representatives* of equivalence classes, when the operation is actually supposed to be defined on the equivalence classes themselves. Here, this means that we need to check that if $(a+Nx)(b+Ny)=c+Nz$ for some $x,y,z$, then $(a+Nx')(b+Ny')=c+Nz'$ for any other $x',y',z'$. [why is this the right thing to check?]

Do you know about cosets? You should probably use those to deal with associativity. In any case, it's not too tedious to do the work manually. $((a+Nx)(b+Ny))(c+Nz)=\cdots?$

Comment: I don't understand. In this group, x=x'=y=y'=0.

Comment: @alek_dv: Ah, you are using a different definition than I am. In that case, I'm not sure what your concern is. In what way are you worried that this operation might not be well-defined?