# Group operation $G,\times_{21}$ with the set set $G=\{3,6,9,12,15,18\}$

Tags: group-theory

Show that the set $G=\{3,6,9,12,15,18\}$ is a group under the operation $\times_{21}$. You should state the inverse of each element in $(G,\times_{21})$.

I'm sure $G_1$-closure $G_2$-Identity and $G_3$-Inverses hold although correct me if I'm wrong, but could someone please show me if $G_4$-Associativity holds. Thanks

Comment: What does "x21" mean?

Comment: x(subscript) 21 is the group operation

Comment: And what is the definition of this operation?...

Comment: Multiplication modulo 21 I would guess. If so, what is the multiplicative identity OP?

Comment: @ah11950:  it seems to $15$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If by $\times_{21}$ you mean multiplication modulo $21$, then you can use the fact that this operation is associative (even in the more general setting of $\mathbb Z_n$). See for example here: [Multiplication group modulo n is well defined,associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501640/multiplication-group-modulo-n-is-well-defined-associative).

Answer (score 1):

Computing powers of 3 (mod 21) you get ${3, 9, 6, 18, 12, 15}$ and then back to 3 again. That makes the set of numbers a cyclic group of order 6 generated by 3 with $3^6 = 15$ the identity.